# IntelliJ IDEA install new fonts

Tags: intellij-idea, truetype

I am running Intellij IDEA 2017.1.1 on Windows 7. I try to add new fonts to Console. I putted Symbola.ttf and Quivira.ttf under ...\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\fonts\ folder and restarted the IDEA. But fonts don't appear in

> Settings -> Editor -> Colors&Fonts-> Console Font

drop-down list. How can I fix it?

Comment: What if you install these fonts and restart IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I installed them also in Windows, but it didn't help

Comment: Do you forgot to **untick** "Show only monospaced fonts"?

Comment: @AKS did my answer help?

Answer (score 6):

TTF fonts can be installed either [globally in the system](https://www.fontspring.com/support/how-do-i-install-fonts-on-my-windows-pc) or into the [JRE that runs IntelliJ IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) (not recommended since it will be overridden during updates).

It looks like you've installed the fonts into the JDK that is not used to run IntelliJ IDEA. This can be verified in `Help` | `About`. Also check that these fonts are monospaced, otherwise they will not be displayed by default.

For the font to appear properly in the IDE you need to have all the versions of the font file (usually 4 different `.ttf` files):

- Normal
- Bold
- Italic
- Bold Italic

If any of these font faces is missing, font may be rendered incorrectly in the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

1.Unzip the archive and install the font:

**mac**:Select all font files in the folder and double-click the “Install Font” button.

**window**:Select all font files in the folder, right-click any of them, then pick “Install” from the menu.

**linux**:Unpack fonts to ~/.local/share/fonts (or /usr/share/fonts, to install fonts system-wide) and fc-cache -f -v

2.Restart your IDE.

3.Go to Preferences/Settings → Editor → Font, and **untick** "show only monospaced fonts"

from https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 build 1809 had changed the old font installed way. If the IDEA (2018.3) did not find the font, we could use these fonts by put them in JB runtime JRE `/lib/font`.

However, in this way, the font render will not as well as idea recognize the same font from 'system font' (by using boulded jre, font will blur, by using Oracle JDK font will too sharp and antialiasing did not do best).

How to repair this:

1. Reinstall font by right clicking the font file (`.ttf`) and select 'install for all users'.
2. Remove font file from  JB runtime JRE `/lib/font` directory.
3. Restart IDEA. It can recognize the font from 'system font' and rendering quality would be satisfied.