# Set local font in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10 20H2, how to add more font to IntelliJ IDEA? I tried to find the entrance to add my font (in my local computer, but I don't know if it is installed), but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Windows Explorer select all font files in the folder, right-click any of them, then pick “Install” from the menu.
2. Restart Intellij
3. Go to Preferences/Settings → Editor → Font, and pick your Font from the Font dropdown.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640146/12844632 .