# Adding more fonts to Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

I was wondering how can import a particular font to Android Studio?, I'm planning to do a sort of translation between a fake "made-up" language based on this font:

https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Rovas-Szabvany-JB-Regular

Therefore, I would like to be able to know if there is a way that android Studio support more fonts, at the moment the font family is very limited.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have any support for fonts by itself. Are you perhaps referring to Android framework? If so, please edit your question to reflect that (and add [tag:android] tag). If not, please clarify

Comment: Is this a question of character encoding? Because that font you linked uses a completely non-standard encoding. Put another way, if you write a text file in that font and then write Kotlin code to open it, you'll just see ordinary letters and numbers since it's using the same bytes as standard ASCII to mean vastly different things. If you're writing a console application and just want the font to show as output, then that's an issue with your terminal that Kotlin has zero control over.

Comment: Kotlin source files use UTF-8 encoding. Font is just a graphical representation of symbols codes. So, if your font doesn't encode symbols with code bigger than 4 bytes, you can just change the font of your kotlin code in any editor, which supports it. You can do it even inside [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-font.html), just make sure you've installed this font into your system, so it would be shown in the respectful dropdown list in editor settings.

Comment: Change the thread to android studio

Comment: Have you seen: [IntelliJ IDEA install new fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65276618/295004)